# colorPrimary not working for android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in Android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, themes, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I have used Toolbar as Actionbar and set background color. I can see colored Toolbar on older version devices but on 4.0 and above it is shown transparent black

I have set Toolbar widget like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and set theme  for app in styles.xml like this\

```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```

Comment: You can save your time and replace `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` with `android:background="#FFFFFF"`

Comment: primaryColor and primaryColorDark have to be different

Comment: What do you have in @color/primaryColor?

Comment: I assume you're sure you don't override `AppBaseTheme` in any of the `values-v[14 etc]` folders?